# Number of ways to sit on seats

Tags: combinatorics

> How many ways are there for $7$ people to sit on $3$ seats?

My attempt:

The number of ways is $P^7_3$ .

Is this correct?

Comment: Are these really big seats?

Comment: Assuming you mean in how many ways can we arrange $3$ of those $7$ people in seats, you are correct.

Comment: Yes , that is what i mean @N.F.Taussig

Comment: @HussienMohamed Are the seats distinct? Are the people distinct?

Comment: @Bram28 The answer to both your questions is yes unless otherwise indicated.  Hussien solved the problem correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.

There are $\binom{7}{3}$ ways to select which three of the seven people will get a seat and $3!$ ways to arrange them in those seats.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{7}{3}3! = P(7, 3)$$
ways to seat three of the seven people in those seats.

Alternatively, there are $7$ ways to choose who sits in the first seat, $6$ ways to choose who sits in the second seat, and $5$ ways to choose who sits in the third seat, which also leads to the answer $P(7, 3)$.